# Is this morphism flat?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abstract-algebra

Suppose $X$ is a smooth projective curve over an algebraically closed field $k$.

Is the morphism $ X \to \operatorname{Spec}(k) $ necessarily flat?

What kind of conditions on the above morphism are equivalent to the hypothesis of $X$ being smooth and projective?

Comment: To answer your second question, $X$ is smooth and projective iff the morphism is smooth and projective. I'm not sure what else you could expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over a field every module (hence every algebra, and hence every scheme) is flat.

By the way, this is a typical situation where various assumptions (smooth, projective, curve, algebraically closed) make the obvious hard to see ...

Comment: Yes thanks Martin for reminding me about this trivial fact: Modules over a field are nothing else than a vector spaces, and these are of course free hence flat.